# Data mismatch in criteria expression in delete oledb command

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I'm simply putting the Oledb command code for delete but the problem is when I delete one of the data from the DGV and there's a message of Data type miss match in criteria expression. Here's the one of my screen shots in this problem:

[image]

Below was the codes here:

```
 Dim com = New OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM CustInfo WHERE Customer_ID = '" & Me.Txt_CusID.Text & "'", con)
        Try
            com.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Delete : SUCCESS!")
            Me.Close()
            ShowTable()
            Txt_CusID.Text = ""
            Txt_Full.Text = ""
            Txt_Add.Text = ""
            Txt_Con.Text = ""
            Txt_Email.Text = ""
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Could you tell me about this problem or lacking something as soon as possible to run this command?

Comment: Most likely `Customer_ID` is a number but you are putting quotes around it making it a string type.

Comment: That has not been the correct way to build SQL for a long time for just this type of problem.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Plutonix , I'm sorry i was new here in this website.

Comment: Crowcoder , from the access??

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.

Comment: @HafBluAnge, I don't understand the question "from the access?". Also, I will not see that you replied unless you address me with @ + username.